# XML Move Nodes Down into another parents

Tags: xml, nodes

I am trying to use Oxygen Editor or R to edit my XML file by moving the some nodes `<file>` to parents `<data>` and `<info>` nodes.

If all the parents nodes are the same, we can do it using `xml2` by finding all the `<file>` nodes remove them and `xml_add_child` to the parents. Then we are done. But the complication is that some `<file>` nodes have `<data>` as the parents and some have `<info>` as the parents. The one thing that may help is that each `<file>` node precedes its supposed parent node, either `<data>` or `<info>`. Is there a way to just extract the `<file>` nodes before the `<data>` nodes? If there is, we are done.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's what we have

```
<file> FILE DATA </file>
<data> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
</data>
<file> FILE DATA </file>
<info> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
</info>
<file> FILE DATA </file>
<info> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
</info>
<file> FILE DATA </file>
<data> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
</data>
  ..................SO ON.................
```

I want the following:

```
<data> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
      <file> FILE DATA </file>
</data>
<info> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
      <file> FILE DATA </file>
</info>
<info> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
      <file> FILE DATA </file>
</info>
<data> 
      <text> TEXT </text>
      <file> FILE DATA </file>
</data>
 .............SO ON .......
```

Comment: Are your XML nodes *really* named `<data>`, `<data2>`, `<data3>` or is this just an example?

Comment: just an example. in fact, there are only only two names, `<data1>` and `<data2>`. But the relative positions are as above, every `<file>`node is immediate above `<data>`

Comment: The question is, are the elements *really* named `<data1>` and `<data2>`, or are they named `<data>` and you invented the `1` and `2`? Because this has influence on how complex the solution is, and if you invented the counter, take it out.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes. It doesn't have the counter. They are either `<data>` or `<information>`. Is there a script that can write to move `<file>` down a level? Like I said before each `<file>` proceeds either `<data>` or `<information>`. THANKS>

Comment: Please update your question with a real XML, and a desired output for it.

Comment: @KevinL, the XML is still not well-formed. It needs a root tag. Everything else could be done via XSLT.